# how to code for gyroActive or gyroAvailable in watchKit in swift language?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, core-motion

I have read below article for  gyroAvailable in watchKit in swift language.

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/gyroActive

but I don't  how to write the code and where do I write(which file)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the gyro code to any class in your watch extension, but you probably want to add it to a subclass of `WKInterfaceController`

Here is want a implementation could look like:

```
import WatchKit
import CoreMotion    

class GyroInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

        let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

        override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
            super.awakeWithContext(context)
            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1
        }

        override func willActivate() {
            super.willActivate()

            if (motionManager.gyroAvailable == true) {
                motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    guard let data = data else { return }
                    let rotationX = data.rotationRate.x
                    let rotationY = data.rotationRate.y
                    let rotationZ = data.rotationRate.z
                    // do you want to want to do with the data
                })
            } else {
                print("Gyro not available")
            }
        }

        override func didDeactivate() {
            super.didDeactivate()
            motionManager.stopGyroUpdates()
        }
    }
```

In theory this should work. If you try this out you will see that it will only print ("Gyro not available"). It seems that the gyro data is not yet accessible. Let's hope that Apple will make it accessible in the not too distant future.

In the meanwhile you could at least use the data from the Accelerometer. That is accessible. The code looks quite similar:

```
import WatchKit
import CoreMotion

class AccelerometerInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true) {
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: { (data, error) -> Void in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                let accelerationX = data.acceleration.x
                let accelerationY = data.acceleration.y
                let accelerationZ = data.acceleration.z
                // do you want to want to do with the data
            })
        }
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()
        motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    }
}
```

Of course this will only work on a Apple Watch and not on the Simulator.

Comment: thnk u .....the reply was helpful...i was able to get the raw data from accelerometer but as u said, not from the gyroscope......

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and looking for some time for an answer and the solution will be to use MotionUpdates.

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let allData = data else { return }
print(allData)// it will return all -> ACC, Gyro,...
}
```